# Using an arcsin transform plus t-test vs Wilcoxon rank test

Tags: data-transformation, nonparametric, proportion, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have some proportion data (percentages). I would like to compare two groups of these proportions to determine if they come from different populations (compare the means).  I have a basic question about comparing distributions of these data: when is it appropriate to use the arcsin transform and a t-test vs using a non-parametric Wilcoxon/Mann-Whitney rank test?

Comment: What is the question you want to answer about the populations of interest? (from which these data presumably represent random samples)

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific - I want to compare the means of two groups to determine if they are from different populations.